# How do you override the default comment template?

Tags: plugins, comments

I have a custom user database that is integrated with a wordpress website using a custom built plugin. I also want to integrate this user system into the comment system.

I have found and completed the code that will handle comment submissions and reject bad ones, but i cannot find out how to actually override the visual side of things. All comment plugins i have used visually change the comment submission form, but i cant find any tutorials on it.

Answer (score 2):

Now what if you have to add/remove fields from default contact form to change the feel of your comment box? I am eliminating website field from default comment box by playing with ‘fields’ argument:in comments.php

```
<?php $comment_args = array('title_reply' => 'Got Something To Say:',
    'fields' => apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields', array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __('Your Good Name') . '</label> ' . ($req ? '<span>*</span>' : '') .
            '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
        'email' => '<p class="comment-form-email">' .
            '<label for="email">' . __('Your Email Please') . '</label> ' .
            ($req ? '<span>*</span>' : '') .
            '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />' . '</p>',
        'url' => '')),
    'comment_field' => '<p>' .
        '<label for="comment">' . __('Let us know what you have to say:') . '</label>' .
        '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .
        '</p>',
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
);
comment_form($comment_args); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can hook your new function to `comment_template()` like this:

```
add_action('comments_template', 'my_function')
```

or

```
function hide_my_comment_template() {
  return null;
}
add_action('comments_template', 'hide_my_comment_template')
```